# Dynamically adding fields based on what is selected in the DropdownField with SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am creating a form (using multiform) where I need to be able to generate checkboxes based on what is selected in the dropdown field containing teams. If one team is picked and that team plays in division 1 and division 2, I want to show division 1 and 2 checkboxes so the user can select which division they play in for that team.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, this is a great module that does this for dependant dropdown field, but I'm sure you can adjust for checkboxes, best of luck!

https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-dependentdropdownfield

Comment: This module requires me to manually enter each possibility. I could do this through jQuery. The reason I am avoiding this is because teams are going to be getting added all the time, I can't keep updating the code every time.

Comment: Well, you need some php to generate the form for you;) Maybe https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic/ can help you? But it's still quite static, you need to generate the form, displaylogic shows and hides other fields for you. Depending on your data this might work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the HTML Code:

```
<select id = "selectMe">
  <option selected = "selected" value = "" >Select Here</option>
  <option value = "sample1">Sample 1</option>
  <option value = "sample2">Sample 2</option>
  <option value = "sample3">Sample 3</option>
</select>

<div class="appendHere"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#selectMe").change(function(){
    $('.appendHere').append('<input type="radio" name="'+$(this).val()+'" value="'+$(this).val()+'"/>'+$(this).val()+'');
});
```

this will give you an idea.. =) cheerio!!

Comment: I know how to append the fields through jQuery but the problem is appending fields differently based on what the selected option is. There is also the problem of SS not actually recognising that field and storing it in the $data variable.

Comment: Hello @JackO'Connor I've updated my answer.. if I understand your problem correctly you want the append radio button to have the value of the selected dropdown right?

Comment: No, the drop down for example would be 'Team1' and team 1 might be part of divisions 2 and 5, if so I would like checkboxes for divisions 2 and 5 and nothing else. This is so when a player is signing up, they would click team 1, and they might only play for division 2 so they would click division 2, but some others might play for division 5 or even both.

Comment: I see... so, how will you determine if that team1 you picked will only have to play for 2 and 5 divisions?

Comment: A team has a many_many relationship with divisions. So there is a division_teams table which links teams to the divisions they participate in

Comment: I see, so you can use jquery ajax for that.. after, selecting the team.. you'll create a query where team = 'teamYouSelected'.. then get where divisions that team will likely to play.. then get the result via json and .each the result... and append the radio button... =)